# HTML href reference JavaScript variable url

Tags: javascript, html

For this question, "example.co.uk" will be the page the user is currently on and "otherexample.co.uk" will be the website I want to link to.

The user loads example.co.uk and selects a date from a html Date input `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { id = "dateselected", type = "date", required = "required", @class = "form-control" })`
And then clicks a `<a href = "">` link, to go to another website that will show available slots for that date. I have tried loads of solutions and can't seem to get any to work.

My Code: 
HTML: 
Date selector -

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="max-width:100%;">
    Date Required: 
</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(
        model => model.Date, new {
            id = "dateselected", 
            type = "date",
            required = "required", 
            @class = "form-control" 
        }
     )
```

href link -

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" href 
="otherexample.co.uk/abuilding&date=" >View Availability</a>
```

So all I want to do is use Javascript to get the selected date from in the date input, and add it to the end of the url in the `href`, so when the user clicks on "View Availability" it sends them to a new page with the url - otherexample.co.uk/abuilding&date=06-21-2018

The options I've found on other sites, including this site, would work great if I was directing to another page on the same website. But can't seem to get any to work for an external website. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using any framework with this? Is the upper code for date selector complete?

Comment: Your query string otherexample.co.uk/abuilding&date=06-21-2018 is not formatted correctly. That might be part of your problem.

Comment: So update the url with the parameter. Is there a framework you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event listener to the `click` event on your link. In the handler function, you could concatenate the date to the link `href` attribute. And then redirect the user with `window.location.href`.

In the snippet below :

- I hard coded a date field with `dateselected` as an id.
- I fixed the href attribute of your link : `https://otherexample.co.uk/abuilding?date=`

```js
document.getElementById("viewAvail").addEventListener("click", viewAbility);

function viewAbility(event) {
  var selectedDate = document.getElementById("dateselected").value;
  window.location.href = event.target.href + selectedDate;
  // preventing de default action of the "click" event since we're changing the windows location
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="dateselected" value="02/06/2018"/>
<a id="viewAvail" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" href 
="https://otherexample.co.uk/abuilding?date=" >View Availability</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you to figure out what you want
 enter date and click button yo will get full url

```js
function get_date(){
var date = document.getElementById("dateselected").value;
 var date_url= document.getElementById("url").href;
 document.getElementById("url_date").innerHTML = date_url +date;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="max-width:100%;">Date Required: 
</label><div class="col-sm-3">
 enter date: <input type="date" id = "dateselected" required = "required" class = "form- 
control"><br>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-primary" id="url" target="_blank" href 
="otherexample.co.uk/abuilding&date=" >View Availability</a>
<button id="click" onclick = "get_date()">click</button>
<p id="url_date"></p>
</body>
</html>
```